# Do we have $f(x)\le\limsup x_n$ for every functional extending limit?

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces

Let us consider functionals $f\colon\ell_\infty\to\mathbb R$ such that:

- $f$ is linear and continuous,
- $f$ extends the usual limit, i.e., if $x=(x_n)$ is convergent and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=a$, then also $f(x)=a$.

**Question.** Do these conditions already imply that $f(x)\le\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$? What are some counterexamples showing that this is not the case?

This came up in the discussion related to [a recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454120/a-necessary-and-sufficient-criterion-for-a-bounded-sequence-a-n-n-1-infty) which is based on T. Tao's blog post [Generalisations of the limit functional](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/05/11/generalisations-of-the-limit-functional/) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20191017170606/https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/05/11/generalisations-of-the-limit-functional/)). You can see some discussion related to that question in the comments on the linked post and [also in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/functionals-on-ell-infty-extending-the-usual-limit).

In that case we have worked with some additional conditions which assure that $f(x)$ is always between $\liminf x_n$ and $\limsup x_n$. (For example, it is sufficient to add $\|f\|=1$ or that $f$ is positive, i.e., $f(x)\ge0$ whenever $x_n\ge0$ for each $n$.) One of the problems in that discussion was that it was unclear why the additional conditions are needed. Perhaps it is reasonable to make a separate question out of it, where this can be presented more clearly.

It might be worth mentioning that one such example can be obtained from this answer: [Continuous extension of the limit functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1043665#1043808). (Although purpose of that question was different.)

I have also posted my attempt to give such example as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider any functional $f$ which fulfills the conditions in the question. Then we define a new functional $g$ by setting
$$g(x)=2f(x_{2n+1})-f(x_{2n})$$
for any sequence $x=(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. I.e., we apply $f$ to the subsequences given by odd/even terms of the original sequence and then we combine these values. For the sake of consistency, let us assume that all sequences are numbered from $n=1$, i.e., $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$

It is easy to see that $g$ is a linear functional. We also have
$$\|g\|\le 3\|f\|,$$
i.e., $g$ is continuous.

The functional $g$ extends limit. Indeed, if $x=(x_n)$ is convergent and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=a$, then we also have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_{2n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_{2n+1}=a$. Consequently, $f(x_{2n})=f(x_{2n+1})=a$ and $g(x)=2a-a=a$.

For this functional we have:

- The sequence $x=(1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,\dots)$ is mapped to $g(x)=3$. So for this sequence the value is bigger than $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n$.
- This also implies $\|g\|\ge3$. (And if we take $f$ such that $\|f\|=1$, then we get $\|g\|=3$.)
- The sequence $y=(0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots)$ is mapped to $g(y)=-1$, so $g$ is not positive.

I will add that "limits" of odd/even terms were also used in this answer: [Hahn–Banach Theorem for Normed Spaces: not unique extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/608920#608931). (Although for different purpose.)